# The process cannot access the file, because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a file in local drive with content by using below code.

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, contents);
```

I am attaching this file to a mail and sending acrross the team. Once mail sent I need to delete the file, to delete the file I am using below code but I am getting runtime error

```
File.Delete(path);
```

**Error Message** : The process cannot access the file, because it is being used by another process

by default WriteAllLines() method closes the file but still it is opened by another process. I can only delete the file by executing the code after sometime but this is not the scenario. I need to delete it once the mail has been sent.

**Update**

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

       mailMessage.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(recipient, ToName));

       mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(From, FromName);
       mailMessage.Subject = Subject; // "Outlook calendar as attachment";  // modified by Srikanth J on 28/06/2012
       mailMessage.Body = "This is a test message";

       System.Net.WebClient webclient = new System.Net.WebClient();

       webclient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

       for (int i = 0; i < item.Attachments.Count; i++)
       {
           string url = item.Attachments.UrlPrefix + item.Attachments[i];
           SPFile file = item.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFile(url);
           mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(file.OpenBinaryStream(), file.Name));

       }

       System.Net.Mail.Attachment mailAttachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path);

       mailMessage.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment);
       smtp.Send(mailMessage);
```

Any help is appriciated, Thank you.

Comment: Seems the process to attach file to mail still holds file?

Comment: Could you post the code where you attach the file? It's most likely there is the problem as @CuongLe suggested.

Comment: @CuongLe You mean even after sending the mail it is still held by the mail process?

Comment: You should post your code. Especially the part that send the attachment and then tries to delete the file.

Comment: @GregorPrimar Updated the question with sending mail code

Comment: @Srikanth can you confirm this facts: 1. this code is used inside webpart and makes access to MS SharePoint SPFile. 2. Error occurs after sending MailMessage and trying to delete SPFile  ?

Comment: Its kind of fuzzy... I cant see any connection between your question and code you have provided in update.

Comment: @GregorPrimar 1) Create file 2) Send file as attachment 3) Delete file. 1) and 3) were in the original question, 2) is the code in the update.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`MailMessage` implements `IDisposable`, so you should be using the `using` keyword to release any resources when you're done with it. If you don't do that, yes, it's very well possible that the file remains in use until the garbage collector happens to notice that you're not using the message anymore.

```
using (var mailMessage = new MailMessage())
{
   // set mailMessage properties
   // ...
   smtp.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

You could also call `Dispose` for the attachment directly, but disposing of a message will already ensure all subobjects, including attachments, get disposed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a simple Using statement to your

```
  System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
```

to change in this way

```
 using(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
 {
       .......
        smtp.Send(mailMessage); 
 }
```

when the your code exit from the using statement the mailMessage object will be disposed as well every object that implements the IDisposable interface. That means, every single Attachment in the Attachments collection will be disposed and your files are no more locked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, I would suggest writing your file to a file to Stream rather than a file.

That way, you can avoid the file locking issue completely.

Here's an example showing how to set up the attachment based on a stream (code to write the stream itself is not shown here).

```
private static void SendReport(Report report)
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage
    {
        From = new MailAddress(Configuration.EmailFrom),
        Subject = Configuration.EmailSubject,
        Body = Configuration.EmailBody
    };

    msg.To.Add(Configuration.EmailTo);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Configuration.EmailCC))
        msg.CC.Add(Configuration.EmailCC);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Configuration.EmailBcc))
        msg.Bcc.Add(Configuration.EmailBcc);

    Program.AttachReport(report, msg);

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Send(msg);
}

private static void AttachReport(Report report, MailMessage message)
{
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    report.Save(stream, Configuration.SurveyName);
    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, Configuration.AttachmentName, Configuration.AttachmentMediaType));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, contents);
using(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage 
                                = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
{
// send mail containing the file here
}
File.Delete(path);
```

Hope this helps u.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

```
try
{
  //send mail code
}
finally
{
  mailAttachment=null;
  mailMessage=null;
}
//delete file code
```

I suggest after sendind mail in finally you relese the file handle or close the file

```
try
{
  //attach file 
  //send mail
}
finally
{
  //set finally handle to null 
  // or close the file
}

//after this delete the file
```

Comment: @L.B - yes thets good idea to use it here i just pasted sudo code for this because op doent provided any code